# Sampling small separators

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, pr.probability, statistical-physics

Is there a tractable way to define an approximate distribution over small vertex separators of the graph? I'm looking for something along the lines of [[Bayati,2008](http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.3373)], a way to turn a single "this is a separator" constraint into a product of several constraints that are easier to enforce. Small true separators may be impossible, in which case approximate separators would do (any cycle that goes through approximate separator must have length >k).

Motivation is constructing a message-passing scheme without short feedback loops.

Comment: I may understand "small vertex separators" as "inclusion minimal (vertex) separators". If so, you could be interested in this paper: [T.Kloks, D.Kratsch. Listing all minimal separators of a graph (1999)](http://www2.cs.uni-paderborn.de/fachbereich/AG/monien/PUBLICATIONS/POSTSCRIPTS/listsiam.ps.Z) (it seems to be the only online-available version, in ZIP format). Note that in general the number of minimal separators is exponential.